# Error java lang NullPointerException mp3 player

Tags: android, web-services, service, nullpointerexception, mp3

See if this time I'm lucky and someone helps me.
I have a mp3 music service on line and am having this error on a

```
service.java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat com.sonysabor.example.musicservice.SongPlay1$6.run(SongPlay1.java:304) at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

the error is on this line:

```
else if(playerStatus == PlayerService.PAUSED)
                {
                    if(Constant.MUSIC_ID.equals(Constant.MUSIC_PLAY_ID_RUNNING))
```

And this is the code fragment Service...

```
progressRefresher.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (playerStatus == PlayerService.PLAYING) {

                    if(Constant.MUSIC_ID.equals(Constant.MUSIC_PLAY_ID_RUNNING))
                    {
                        refreshTrack();

                    //  isPlay=true;

                    }
                    else if((Constant.MUSIC_ID.equals(Constant.MUSIC_PLAY_ID)))
                    {
                        refreshTrackNone();
                        refreshButtonsNone();

                    //  isPlay=false;
                    }   

                }
                else if(playerStatus == PlayerService.PAUSED)
                {
                    if(Constant.MUSIC_ID.equals(Constant.MUSIC_PLAY_ID_RUNNING))
                    {
                        //isPlay=false;
                    }
                    else if((Constant.MUSIC_ID.equals(Constant.MUSIC_PLAY_ID)))
                    {
                        refreshTrackNone();
                        refreshButtonsNone();
                    //  isPlay=false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 0, 500);
    /*
```

This is Logcat:

```
01-27 20:18:04.444: E/Music Play Id(539): 46
01-27 20:18:04.444: E/Onstart(539): called
01-27 20:18:04.444: W/dalvikvm(539): threadid=32: thread exiting with          uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
01-27 20:18:04.454: E/poswewew---->(539): 0
01-27 20:18:04.454: E/AndroidRuntime(539): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
01-27 20:18:04.454: E/AndroidRuntime(539): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 20:18:04.454: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at com.sonysabor.example.musicservice.SongPlay1$6.run(SongPlay1.java:302)
01-27 20:18:04.454: E/AndroidRuntime(539):  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
01-27 20:18:04.604: E/array(539): http://nube.myweb.com/mp3/vallenato/Senora_Otto_Serge_Rafael_Ricardo.mp3
01-27 20:18:04.994: D/dalvikvm(539): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 237K, 26% free 9958K/13447K, paused 362ms
01-27 20:18:05.614: D/dalvikvm(539): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 31K, 20% free 10808K/13447K, paused 423ms
01-27 20:18:05.844: E/MediaPlayer(539): stop called in state 1
01-27 20:18:05.854: E/MediaPlayer(539): error (-38, 0)
01-27 20:18:05.924: W/MediaPlayer(539): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
01-27 20:18:07.335: I/Process(539): Sending signal. PID: 539 SIG: 9
01-27 20:18:22.674: E/MediaPlayer(621): start called in state 1
01-27 20:18:22.674: E/MediaPlayer(621): error (-38, 0)
01-27 20:18:22.674: E/MediaPlayer(621): Error (-38,0)
01-27 20:18:22.674: E/MediaPlayer(621): stop called in state 0
```

Comment: Post complete call stack of logcat logs

Comment: Constant.MUSIC_ID must be null

Comment: @Aashish Hi have put the logcat :-)